# Creating LinkedIn App. Why is my company not listed?

Tags: linkedin-api

I just got admin access to the company page and even added it as my current position.

Still, when creating an app here https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/new the given company/page is not listed on the dropdown. Any tips?

Comment: I solved the problem by using mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. My problem was that I was trying to use a Showcase rather than a Company page.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an app right?
What you may need to do is add a Company Page.

Comment: Note that if the company (page) didn't exist I couldn't even add it on my profile in the first place. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I would really comment that instead of replying, but since I don't have enough rep I can't. Anyways..
If you can add the company name to your current profile, it may probably be a bug. I would contact the support of them if you have already followed every step they gave.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks :) Funnily enough their support page pointed me here... (They don't really have support)

Answer (score 1):

Guess I was just a victim of bad UI (?)

So, turns out that "creating a new company" on that interface does not really mean "create a new company page".

If you are with the same problem, just select "Create a new company" and type the name. Company pages will pop up.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. If "creating a new company" does not work, how will selecting "create a new company" help?

Comment: "create a new company" on the developer portal is not the same as "creating a company" in likedin itself, this is what i tried to pass across i guess. bear in mind this was 3 years ago ...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be LinkedIn company search issue. It can occur when your company name is too common. As a workaround, you can temporarily add a unique part to your company name.

For example, if your company name is "Dog Store", then you may want to change it temporarily to "Dog Store (DOG168)". Now try to search by "DOG168" on the create an application page. This trick helped in my case.