# Could not associate a company page with a new app

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want to create a new app on [developers portal](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/new)  and link it to an existing [company page](https://www.linkedin.com/company/remotesome/).

When I start writing the company name (Remotesome) it just says:

> No companies found by that name.

I expect the company to be found there - it's a newly created company page and I did not create it - could this be the problem?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I thought maybe it was because it was a new page and it needed time to propagate through the system, but it has been five days and it still isn't showing up.

Comment: Your company name (Remotesome) is showing up for me. Mine (Ready Russian) still isn't.

Comment: @David42 - I can see yours (Ready Russian) but not mine :/ I suspect this is a bug...

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929187/creating-linkedin-app-why-is-my-company-not-listed?rq=1 As of today none of the answers to that question are informative. One suggests maybe you don't really have a company page, one simply provides a link which is dead, and one is too garbled to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today - I can add the company to the app. For some unknown reason it did not appear before but now it does. So it could be that it takes some time - up to 7 days for it to appear.